# How to load CSS and js assets inside Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am confused about this part in Vue even after reading the docs. How should I load assets from `index.html`? I tried referring to assets using different methods, here is the one I am trying now that is still not working

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/magnific-popup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/slinky.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/bundle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/responsive.css">
```

Comment: You can't reference the styles from there because those styles in the `src` folder will be bundled into the final package. If they are static and not imported by your templates/components when building, they are probably better off in the `public` folder where you can reference them as stated in the docs: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

Comment: Problem solved, Thank you @Terry . Can you write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further elabourating on my answer: when those CSS files are placed in your `src` folder, they will only be included in your bundle when they are required by your Vue components, or imported dynamically. Since these are static assets, they should simply be placed in your app's `public` folder instead, and then you can reference these assets using `<%= BASE_URL %>` as the root path in your `index.html`.

The [VueJS documentation has more details on how you can do that](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder).